# Python: list.pop(0) gives index error while list is full

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to get back a list of **n** shops in order such that they are neighbours and then, if necessary, neighbours of neighbours. Below is code that is used to calculate this list called **locations**. The shops are numbered from 1 to 10 inclusively.

In this case each shop has 4 neighbours. This relationship is set randomly in the dictionary called **neighbours**.

```
import random

shops = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

neighbours = {}

for i in shops:
    neighbours[i] = random.sample(shops, 4)
    while i in neighbours[i]:
        neighbours[i] = random.sample(shops, 4)
print (neighbours)
shop_zero = random.randrange(1,11)
locations = [shop_zero]
neighborhd = neighbours[locations[0]]
n=10
while len(locations) < n:
    if not neighborhd:
        print('if statement')
        neighborhd = neighbours[random.choice(locations)]
        print (neighborhd)
    print('while loop')
    ne = neighborhd.pop(0)
    if ne not in locations:
        locations.append(ne)
print (locations)
```

The problem is that the code works *sometimes* but often it give me an index error:

```
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

For those interested, the following is the output for the neighbours dictionary:

```
{1: [7, 5, 4, 9], 2: [5, 6, 3, 7], 3: [10, 8, 7, 6], 4: [7, 8, 10, 2], 5: [3, 6, 1, 9], 6: [5, 1, 10, 3], 7: [3, 8, 6, 2], 8: [10, 4, 9, 7], 9: [6, 5, 3, 2], 10: [3, 5, 8, 7]}
```

I've added some print statements to make the working example more informative. As I said earlier, it does work every so often but mostly it gives the index error. 
Please help?

P.S. I realise that the resulting list doesn't always give me the clusters but rather a path to follow from neighbour to neighbour. This is fine for the project I am working on.

Comment: Put a `print(neighborhd)` just before the `pop(0)` and see it's value.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the line `neighborhd = neighbours[random.choice(locations)]` will always give you a non-empty list. I don't see any reason why that would be true. Can you clarify your reasoning?

Comment: @A.Far Please have a look my answer below. thanks

Comment: @MarkDickinson Well I've filled in the `neighbours` dictionary by sampling the `locations` list 4 times right?
Then I've set the keys of the dictionary to be numbers from 1-10 (the elements of `locations'). Doesn't that guarantee that every possible key is associated with a non-empty list?
Am I missing something?

Comment: @A.Far: Right, but in each of the 10 iterations you remove an element from one of those lists (in the line `ne = neighborhd.pop(0)`). If the random numbers turn up right, you end up removing all four elements of one of the lists, hence the error. That is, you're *modifying* the contents of `neighbours` as the while loop progresses. Maybe that wasn't what you wanted to do.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Ah thanks! I'm new to python and didn't realise that lists are passed by reference rather than by value. I thought `neighbours` would be safe unless I explicitly changed it. 

Thanks again. This solves my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I altered your code help debugging which you can see below. If you run this you find that when the exception is thrown the 'neighbours' dictionary has empty lists as some of the values. This means that it is possible for 'neighborhd' to be repopulated with an empty list from 'neighbours' and so still be empty.

```
import random

shops = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

neighbours = {}

for i in shops:
    neighbours[i] = random.sample(shops, 4)
    while i in neighbours[i]:
        neighbours[i] = random.sample(shops, 4)
print (neighbours)
shop_zero = random.randrange(1,11)
locations = [shop_zero]
neighborhd = neighbours[locations[0]]
n=10
while len(locations) < n:
    if not neighborhd:
        print('if statement')
        neighborhd = neighbours[random.choice(locations)]
        print (neighborhd)
    print('while loop')
    try:
        ne = neighborhd.pop(0)
    except IndexError:
        raise IndexError("Attempt to pop from neighborhd which has content %s, formed from neighbours which has content %s" % (neighborhd, neighbours))
    if ne not in locations:
        locations.append(ne)
print (locations)
```

Comment: Ah thanks for figuring out what was going on! Do you have any idea why my dictionary sets some of the values to empty lists? I explicitly check that they're not empty (by reading it out) before the while loop in the line `print (neighbours)`.

Comment: When you assign one of the lists from 'neighbours' to 'neighborhd' Python does not copy the list but makes a new reference to it. You the remove members from the list 'neighborhd' is pointing at but this list in still a value in 'neighbours'. This means that when 'neighborhd' becomes empty one of the lists in 'neighbours' is also empty.

Comment: Have a read about python and how variables are references. Also look up python copy as you may want to use that here.

Comment: Yep, I realise that now. I'm moving from C++ and it's a wonderful, and at times confusing, world here in python. I'll read up on how variables are treated so I don't run into this kind of thing again.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have problem in `neighborhd = neighbours[random.choice(locations)]`. It also returning empty list. so you need to make little change. `if  neighborhd:` to before `pop` just check it's not an empty list.

```
 import random

shops = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

neighbours = {}

for i in shops:
    neighbours[i] = random.sample(shops, 4)
    while i in neighbours[i]:
        neighbours[i] = random.sample(shops, 4)
print (neighbours)
shop_zero = random.randrange(1,11)
locations = [shop_zero]
neighborhd = neighbours[locations[0]]
n=10
while len(locations) < n:
    if not neighborhd:
        print('if statement')
        neighborhd = neighbours[random.choice(locations)]
        print (neighborhd)
    print('while loop')
    if neighborhd:
        ne = neighborhd.pop(0)
        if ne not in locations:
            locations.append(ne)
print (locations)
```

Comment: when both `neighborhd` and `neighbours` are empty this makes an infinite loop. Try putting it in a for loop `for j in range(10000):` and run it and after about 10 it will hit an infinite loop.

Comment: @rassar, my bad Code format changed the code. try now.

Comment: @RuhulAmin Thanks! This works :-) Though my question is why does the error occur? I have `print (neighbours)` before the while loop just as my own sanity check that no value in the dictionary is an empty list. Which it isn't. But for some reason, sometimes, some values become empty lists. Any idea why?

Comment: @A.Far, You said, my code works for you but you accepted other answer, does not make sense

Comment: @RuhulAmin Yes your code works for me and thanks for that. But the other answer provides details as to why my code didn't work. The code they provided demonstrates exactly where my bug is and what is causing it, which are things I wanted to know when I asked the question here and the answer I picked deals with those questions to my satisfaction. 

No hard feelings!